# next-auth type error with getServerSession

Tags: typescript, next.js, next-auth

I'm getting a type error when calling the `getServerSesssion` function and passing all the required parameters. I have a function `getServerAuthSession`:

```js
import { authOptions } from '@/pages/api/auth/[...nextauth]';
import type { GetServerSidePropsContext } from 'next';
import { getServerSession } from 'next-auth/next';

export const getServerAuthSession = (ctx: {
  req: GetServerSidePropsContext['req'];
  res: GetServerSidePropsContext['res'];
}) => {
  return getServerSession(ctx.req, ctx.res, authOptions);
};
```

But I get the following type error:

```
Argument of type '[IncomingMessage & { cookies: Partial<{ [key: string]: string; }>; }, ServerResponse<IncomingMessage>, { adapter: Adapter; providers: OAuthConfig<...>[]; secret: string | undefined; cookies: { ...; }; callbacks: {}; }]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'GetServerSessionParams<GetServerSessionOptions>'.
  Type '[IncomingMessage & { cookies: Partial<{ [key: string]: string; }>; }, ServerResponse<IncomingMessage>, { adapter: Adapter; providers: OAuthConfig<...>[]; secret: string | undefined; cookies: { ...; }; callbacks: {}; }]' is not assignable to type '[IncomingMessage & { cookies: Partial<{ [key: string]: string; }>; }, ServerResponse<IncomingMessage>, GetServerSessionOptions]'.
    Type at position 2 in source is not compatible with type at position 2 in target.
      Type '{ adapter: Adapter; providers: OAuthConfig<GoogleProfile>[]; secret: string | undefined; cookies: { sessionToken: { name: string; options: { httpOnly: boolean; sameSite: string; path: string; domain: string; secure: boolean; }; }; }; callbacks: {}; }' is not assignable to type 'GetServerSessionOptions'.
        Type '{ adapter: Adapter; providers: OAuthConfig<GoogleProfile>[]; secret: string | undefined; cookies: { sessionToken: { name: string; options: { httpOnly: boolean; sameSite: string; path: string; domain: string; secure: boolean; }; }; }; callbacks: {}; }' is not assignable to type 'Partial<Omit<AuthOptions, "callbacks">>'.
          Types of property 'adapter' are incompatible.
            Type 'Adapter' is not assignable to type 'Adapter<boolean> | undefined'.
              Type 'Adapter' is not assignable to type 'DefaultAdapter & { createVerificationToken: (verificationToken: VerificationToken) => Awaitable<VerificationToken | null | undefined>; useVerificationToken: (params: { ...; }) => Awaitable<...>; }'.
                Type 'Adapter' is not assignable to type 'DefaultAdapter'.
                  Types of property 'createUser' are incompatible.
                    Type '((user: Omit<AdapterUser, "id">) => Awaitable<AdapterUser>) | undefined' is not assignable to type '(user: Omit<AdapterUser, "id">) => Awaitable<AdapterUser>'.
                      Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type '(user: Omit<AdapterUser, "id">) => Awaitable<AdapterUser>'.ts(2345)
```

I've followed the config as per the documentation here: https://next-auth.js.org/configuration/nextjs

Any pointers would greatly be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the error, in your `[...nextauth].ts` file, you are using an adapter of type `Adapter` so `authOptions` passed as 3rd parameter to `getServerSession`, is not assignable to what should be there, the error tells that type `Adapter` is not assignable to type `DefaultAdapter`.

in [this section](https://next-auth.js.org/getting-started/typescript#adapters) there is an example of using adapters with TypeScript in next-auth. 
 they import `Adapter` from `"next-auth/adapters"` but I think you should use an adapter of type `DefaultAdapter` in your `authOptions` object so in `[...nextauth].ts` file.

```js
import { DefaultAdapter } from "next-auth/adapters";
```